# How to make a response interceptor in RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rtk-query

I need to redirect to log in screen and clear the authentication token when the response status from an API is unauthorized.
I could do this in Angular easily by providing an HTTP interceptor to the module, so I'm looking for an equivalent in RTK Query in React.
Is there a way to add a global interceptor via RTK query? Or an interceptor for the response to a group of queries?
I thought of implementing the logic to do the above using the `transformResponse` field but doing it there doesn't seem right, and I'll have to add the function call to the body of every `transformResponse` callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do that by wrapping your `fetchBaseQuery`. There is an example that does this for re-authorization in the documentation:

[Automatic re-authorization by extending fetchBaseQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery)

```
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' })
const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
  if (result.error && result.error.status === 401) {
    // your logic here
  }
  return result
}
```